# How to get the results with count 0 too with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, count

I am using the `Projections.rowCount()` function on Hibernate, but it will only return the counts greater than 0. I need to get the list with the 0 count too.

This is the function supposed to give me the count but it only returns counts greater than 1.

```
public List<Object[]> getCuentaPorEnlotar() {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = casosEstadoCriteria(Caso.EstadoOperativo.COMPLETADO, Caso.EstadoAdministrativo.TARIFICADO);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("lote"));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("cliente"))
            .add(Projections.rowCount()));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("cliente"));
    return (List<Object[]>) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't rowCount() return 0 if no records are found?  What are you getting back when there are no records?

Comment: whenever there is no record that meets my specifications, i get none row at all.
what this query usually returns is a List<Object[]>, being each Object[] a two size vector containing on the [0] position a "cliente" and on the [1] position the count (whenever it is greater than 1). if it isn't greater than 1, it will not return that record at all, meaning no cliente nor count (no entry on the List<Object>).